# Jquery browser history js - same action doesnt fire second time - no state change workaround

Tags: history.js

Using [browserstate/history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

All my links are running through the history adapter:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {

// do some stuff here

});
```

but if a user clicks the same link twice in a row then the second time it will not run since there is no 'statechange'. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add random data to differentiate the actions:

```
History.replaceState( {randomData: window.Math.random()}, '', url);
```

That way statechange will always fire.

Found answer here https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/293